# How do I convert my C# wpf code to an application that I can run without Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I made a fully functional wpf game with visual studio and I need to send it to someone without visual studio. I basically need him to click an .exe file that makes the game run. How would I do this?

Comment: The executable file is created in the output folder of your Visual Studio project, typically `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release`, depending on the project configuration you are building.

Comment: He/she will need dotnet framework installed - a version matches whatever you compiled for. Other than that it should "just" be a filecopy install of whatever  you have out your debug or release folder. If you're writing to save files in that folder then make sure they copy to a writeable folder rather than under program files. FYI If you had built a net core 3 wpf app you could potentially compile all your dll into the exe so there was just one thing to copy. Oh. And the core 3 framework to install.

Answer (score 2):

See [Building a WPF App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/building-a-wpf-application-wpf)

Here are the step by step instructions.

First change the build type to Release.

[image]

Then right click your project from the solution explorer and click Build.

[image]

Last of all right click your project and select Open Folder in File Explorer.

[image]

Navigate to the Bin>Release folder. There you will find the executable file.

[image]